# Use AverMedia TV tunner in Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tuner-card

I have a AverMedia TV tuner (internal) and work well in windows .
Are there anyone use it in Ubuntu or other  Linux distribution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that it depends on version. I had  AVerTV Hybrid Volar HX, and that card had Linux support.

Comment: have a link of this ?

Comment: http://www.avermedia.com/AVerTV/Product/ProductDetail.aspx?Id=293&tab=APDriver